# Jquery mouseleave element unwanted behaviour

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I am trying to create a simple jquery menu but encounter a problem. Here is my script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#tm-u, #tm-e, #tm-n').click(function(){
 $( '#topmenu' ).css('display', 'block');
});
$('#topmenu').mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
});
</script>
```

My html structure is this:

```
<div id="login">
<a href="#tm-u">1</a>
<a href="#tm-e">1</a>
<a href="#tm-n">1</a>
</div

<div id="topmenu">
stuff
</div>
```

The thing is that the topmenu appears UNDER the login element (using z-index) because I want the menu to appear under it and keep the functionality of the login buttons to change content inside 'topmenu'.

However using mouseleave, whenever the cursor enters the login element the topmenu closes and I want it to stay open.

So in other words, I want the topmenu element to stay visible even when you hover on the login element that is sitting above it.

How can I do this? I tried using this code but it's not working :/

```
$('#login').mouseenter(function(){
if ($('#topmenu').is(':visible')) {
alert('h');
$( '#topmenu' ).css('display', 'block');
};
});
```

Comment: please use `jsfiddle.net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution would be to change your markup, and wrap both elements (`#login` and `#topmenu`). Then bind the `mouseleave` handler to their parent.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loginWrapper">
  <div id="login">
    <a href="#tm-u">1</a>
    <a href="#tm-e">1</a>
    <a href="#tm-n">1</a>
  </div>

  <div id="topmenu">
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('.loginWrapper').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#topmenu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

This way, your mouse will have to leave the wrapper, and all of it's children, in order to fire.

Comment: This is actually a very good idea, need to work it a bit, because most elements are aligned absolutely and have to be changed. Let me test this and get back to you. However, wouldn't this also be wrong since the other elements are on top of it?

Comment: Yup, it's working! Thanks! :) It's hard to think as dev when you are a designer... :}

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CSS problem.

Try this...

```
#topmenu:hover,
#login:hover + #topmenu {
  display: block;
}
```